# Como hacer un where en laravel

Tags: php

En mi controlador tengo un:

```
$objeto1 = Objeto1::all();
```

El modelo `Objeto1` tiene un metodo:

```
public function object2() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Objeto2::class);
}
```

Ahora necesito cambiar en el controlador a algo como un:

```
$objeto1 = Objeto1::find()->where(idDelObjeto2)= 2
```

Pero no tengo claro como seria el sintaxis correcto, tampoco se como acceder al id del Objeto2

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer un `whereHas`, te quedaría algo así :

```
$objeto1 = Objeto1::whereHas('objeto2', function($query){ 
               $query->where('id', idDelObjeto2 ); 
           })->get();
```

Lo que hace la función `whereHas` es referenciarte otra tabla.

Si aparte necesitas traer la información del objeto2 tenes que hacer un `with`, te quedaría algo así :

```
$objeto1 = Objeto1::whereHas('objeto2', function($query){ 
               $query->where('id', idDelObjeto2 ); 
           })->with('objeto2')->get();
```

Saludos